# How to register a COM assembly in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, com

I am at my wit's end trying to register a COM assembly. I keep getting that (rather unhelpful error) stating

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {GuidID} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

This assembly is part of a reference to a  library written in .NET 4.5. That library is a reference in a .NET 4.5 webservice. The assembly is Interop.AssemblyName. I have verified that the Interop.AssemblyName.dll exists in the bin folder for the webservice. These projects were just upgraded from .NET 2.0 using VS2012.

I have tried registering the assembly with REGSVR32.exe, (fails, with no DLLEntryPoint), gacutil.exe (says it installed correctly) and Regasm (32 bit and 64 bit, both say the install was successful) Lastly, I have tried changing the build output to be "x86" from "Any CPU".

None of this stuff above has done anything to resolve this error. What else could this stupid assembly possibly want to be registered with before it decides to function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up the native COM component and the interop library that was generated for it.  What's missing is that native COM component, the interop library plays no role in getting it registered properly.  The interop library is only there to make it easy for the CLR to use the component.  It should *not* be registered, the reason that Regsvr32.exe complains.

It doesn't sound like you've found that native component yet, we can't help you find it either.  The `<COMReference>` entry in the project file would be a hint to help you locate it, the Guid element tells you where to look in the registry with Regedit.exe.  But it needs to be installed on the machine to get rid of this runtime error.  Contact the owner or vendor of the component for install instructions.

And do note that a web service typically runs in 64-bit mode.  Legacy COM components are almost always 32-bit only.  You'll need a 32-bit application pool on the server to stay compatible.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this helps clear some things up for me. Where would I find the <COMReference> entry? I looked in the .csproj file xml for both the assembly that referenced the interop and the the WebService that referenced the assembly. I did not see any <COMReference> tag. I was also using ILSpy to look at the Interop, hoping there would be a clue, but did not find anything useful. Do you have any other ideas of where I could search for hints?

Comment: Well I happened upon a lucky Google Search and found someone having issues with the same Interop. From their post, I was able to find out the corresponding COM name. Once I REGSVR32ed the correct .dll, I was able to get rid of the runtime error. Thank you for your help.